# Is it possible to update only latitude or longitude in postgis?

Tags: postgis, point, coordinates, update

I have a postgis database that contains Points created based on a couple (longitude, latitude), and I need to update only one of those two for a given point.

I found that it's possible to do so but to modify both of the coordinates using :

```
UPDATE poi SET place = ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326; POINT(' || "+lg+" ||' '|| "+lat+" || ')') where mykey='"+key+"';
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Is your data in Geometry type or Geography?

Comment: The object I want to update is "place" and I created it this way : place GEOGRAPHY(POINT,4326)

Comment: I have added the code for geography type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input geometry needs to be built from the existing geometry.

If I want to just change the Y coordinate (i.e. Latitude) to 66.23, I can use the following command (when data is of type geometry):

```
update mytable 
       set the_geom=ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(ST_X(the_geom), 66.23), 4326)
                      where gid=9;
```

Since your data is in Geography type, you can use a SQL command like this:

```
update mytable 
       set place =ST_GeographyFromText('POINT('||ST_X(place::geometry)||' 66.23)') 
              where where gid=9;
```

Comment: What is the equivalent for GEOGRAPHY type ? 
Thanks

Comment: @user1651994: See the Update

Comment: I'll try it and give a feedback asap

Comment: It is working fine ! Thank you :) 
For the ones who may be interested, I used the following query to check if everything is ok : 
SELECT st_X(Geometry(place)), st_Y(Geometry(place)) FROM poi where myid= 'id';